# When I run this, it states that the list constraints is unbound. Why is that?

Tags: list, nested, lisp, common-lisp, prefix

```
(defun combinations (&rest lists) (if (car lists) (mapcan (lambda (inner-val)(mapcar (lambda (outer-val) (cons outer-val inner-val)) (car lists))) (apply #'combinations (cdr lists))) (list nil)))
```

The combinations function creates all combinations of the names, charms and position for each baseball player.

```
(defun main()
  (setq m-list (combinations '(Blacket Bluet Browning Greenfield Whitehall)'(four-lear-clover penny rabbit-foot ribbon silver-dollar) '(center-    field first-base right-field short-stop third-base)))
  (setq contraints  (list '(no Browning penny) '(no Browning silver-dollar) '(no Browning right-field) '(no Browning center-field) '(no Bluet center-field) '(no Bluet right-field) '(no Greenfield first-base) '(no Greenfield short-stop)
    '(no Greenfield third-base) '(no Whitehall center-field) '(no Whitehall right-field) '(no Greenfield four-leaf-clover) '(no Greenfield penny) '(no Whitehall four-lear-clover) '(no Whitehall penny) 
    '(no Blacket four-leaf-clover) '(no Blacket penny) '(no Blacket first-base) '(no Blacket third-base) '(no Blacket ribbon) '(no Bluet ribbon) '(no center-field rabbit-foot)))
  (loop  
   (setf n-constraint (car constraints))
   (setf m-list (remove-l m-list n-constraint))
   (setf constraints (cdr constraints))
   (when (null constraints) (return m-list))))
```

The main function serves to solve a problem where none of the players positions and charm are known. The main function makes a list of all possible combinations of the players, their charms, and their baseball position. It then declares a list of constraints with each list stating no, in the beginning to indicate that both values after the no should not be in any combination. A loop is made in order to take one constraint from the constraint list. The car of the constraints is a list itself. Main then uses the remove-l function to eliminate combinations that don't agree with the constraints. Remove-l then returns a new m-list with fewer combinations than before

```
(defun remove-l (a b)
  (setf n-list '())
  (loop 
    (setf sample (car a))
    (when (and (not (= (find (nth 1 b) sample) nil) (= (find (nth 2 b)sample) nil))) (cons sample (cons n-list nil)))
(setf a (cdr a))(when (null a) (return n-list))))
```

Remove-l function here serves return a new list with most of the same combinations as before. One constraint from the constraints list is used to eliminate certain combinations.

```
(defvar  *data* nil)
```

> ignore

```
(defun add-player (player)
  (push player *data*))
```

> ignore

```
(defun dump-data ()
  (dolist (cd *data*)
   (format t "~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%" cd)))
```

> ignore

Comment: Perhaps because you spelled "constraints" as "contraints"?

Comment: Apart from that it seems you didn't define `constraints` anywhere.

Comment: SETF and SETQ don't define variables. You have zillions of undefined variables in your code. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Xach already pointed out the spelling mistake in the comments, but I figured I'd add some comments regarding your code.

You should not define variables with `SETQ` or `SETF`. Those should be used only to set values to already defined variables. Use [`LET`/`LET*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) for local variables, or [`DEFVAR`/`DEFPARAMETER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) for globals.

Looping over lists is also such a common thing to do that there are built in constructs for it: [`DOLIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm) and in extended `LOOP`s you can use `FOR element IN list`.

After fixing those and adding some better indentation to your `REMOVE-L`, it would look like this:

```
(defun remove-l (a b)
  (let ((n-list '()))
    (dolist (sample a n-list) ; That N-LIST is the return value from the loop
      (when (and (not (= (find (nth 1 b) sample)
                         nil)
                      (= (find (nth 2 b) sample)
                         nil)))
        (cons sample (cons n-list nil))))))
```

That still has some problems. Notice how the `AND` only has one form in it, and the `NOT` has two. `=` is meant for numeric equality, so you should use `NOT` or [`NULL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_null.htm) to check if something is non-true. Then there's of course the problem that `CONS` is not destructive; you have to set its return value to someplace. As it is now, the loop does not do anything. You could use [`PUSH`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm) to add elements to a list.

Fixing those, you would have something like this:

```
(defun remove-l (a b)
  (let ((n-list '()))
    (dolist (sample a n-list)
      (when (and (not (find (nth 1 b) sample))
                 (not (find (nth 2 b) sample)))
        (push sample n-list)))))
```

You could further improve it by assigning the two constraints to variables (using either `LET` or [`DESTRUCTURING-BIND`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm)) instead of calling `NTH` twice per iteration. 
However, filtering a list is also a very common thing to do and your `REMOVE-L` could be easily expressed with the built-in [`REMOVE-IF`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm). You could change your `MAIN` to something like this:

```
(defun main ()
  (let ((m-list ...) ; I left out the long lists. Fill them in.
        (constraints ...))
    ;; This uses LOOPs destructuring assignment. The underscore is
    ;; just an unused variable that holds the NO in each constraint.
    ;; CONSTRAINT-1 and -2 hold the two symbols.
    (loop for (_ constraint-1 constraint-2) in constraints
          do (setf m-list (remove-if (lambda (sample)
                                       ;; I used MEMBER instead of FIND.
                                       ;; It doesn't really matter, but
                                       ;; MEMBER communicates intent better.
                                       (and (member constraint-1 sample)
                                            (member constraint-2 sample)))
                                     m-list)))
    m-list))
```

**Edit:** Now that I remembered, Common Lisp also has a built in function [`SUBSETP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subset.htm#subsetp) to check if a list is a subset of another list (disregarding order). With that you don't need to destructure the constraint list.

```
(defun main ()
  (let ((m-list ...)
        (constraints ...))
    (dolist (constraint constraints m-list)
      (setf m-list (remove-if (lambda (sample)
                                (subsetp (cdr constraint)
                                         sample))
                              m-list)))))
```

This would be a good place to use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which is not built in, but if you have [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) installed you can use the implementation from [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) or you can just write a simple one yourself:

```
(defun curry (function &rest arguments)
  (lambda (&rest more)
    (multiple-value-call function (values-list arguments) (values-list more))))

(defun main ()
  (let ((m-list ...)
        (constraints ...))
    (dolist (constraint constraints m-list)
      (setf m-list (remove-if (curry #'subsetp (cdr constraint))
                              m-list)))))
```

Comment: Not to mention that `=` is for numerical equality and `nil` is many things, but not a number. *edit* Doh! You already mentioned that.