# How to remove elements a list within a list that contains two elements that you don't want?

Tags: list, loops, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun combinations (&rest lists) (if (car lists) (mapcan (lambda (in-val) (mapcar (lambda (out-val) (cons out-val in-val)) (car lists))) (apply #'combinations (cdr lists))) (list nil)))
```

> This function makes a combination of any number of lists.

```
(defun main()
  (setq m-list (combinations '(Blacket Bluet Browning Greenfield Whitehall) '(four-leaf-clover penny rabbit-foot ribbon silver-dollar) '(center-field first-base right-field short-stop third-base)))

  (setq constraints  (list '(Browning penny) '(Browning silver-dollar) '(Browning right-field) '(Browning center-field) '(Bluet center-field) '(Bluet right-field) '(Greenfield first-base) '(Greenfield short-stop)
    '(Greenfield third-base) '(Whitehall center-field) '(Whitehall right-field) '(Greenfield four-leaf-clover) '(Greenfield penny) '(Whitehall four-leaf-clover) '(Whitehall penny) 
    '(Blacket four-leaf-clover) '(Blacket penny) '(Blacket first-base) '(Blacket third-base) '(Blacket ribbon) '(Bluet ribbon) '(center-field rabbit-foot)))
  (loop  
    (print m-list)
    (setq n-constraint (car constraints))
    (setq m-list (remove-it m-list n-constraint))
    (setq constraints (cdr constraints))
    (when (null constraints) (return m-list))))
```

> The main function creates two lists, a list of all the possible combinations of players, charms, and positions, and a list of constraints, where two variables in each constraint list cannot be together. I then created a loop in order to take one constraint each iteration and remove from the main list of combinations the combination that matches what the constraint says should not exist.

```
(defun remove-it (x y) 
    (if (and (not (eq (find (nth 0 y) (car x)) nil) (not (eq (find (nth 1 y)(car x)) nil)))) (setq x (remove (car x) x :test #'equal)))
    (return x))
```

> For some reason the remove-it function only manages to remove everything related to the constraint. For example, a constraint is (Browning penny). The intention is to remove any list inside the massive combinations list that contains the two elements Browning and penny together. However, the function seems to remove every list that contains Browning separately and penny. I only want the function to remove lists that have Browning and Penny together.

Comment: Did you read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37164868/5747548) to your previous question? You seem to be still making the same mistakes I already pointed out.

Comment: Also check the nesting of your boolean expression in `remove-it`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with indenting your `remove-it` function:

```
(defun remove-it (x y) 
  (if (and (not (eq (find (nth 0 y) (car x)) nil)
                (not (eq (find (nth 1 y)(car x)) nil))))
      (setq x (remove (car x) x :test #'equal)))
  (return x))
```

This is rather nonsensical, as functions go. The `not` function typically takes only a single argument, you're (most probably) missing a closing parenthesis after the first `not` call.

You are also only checking the very first element of `x`, so if that's OK, you're not checking the rest of the list.

Your variable names are less than clear (what does "x" and "y" actually mean).

You don't need an explicit return, just having `x` as a single expression at the end would work.

A possibly-better solution might be (based on my understanding of what you actually want to do, namely "collect all combinations that don't have two banned combos):

```
(defun remove-constrained-combinations (combinations constraint-1 constraint-2)
  (loop for combo in combinations
        unless (and (member constraint-1 combinations)
                    (member constraint-2 combinations)
        collect combo))
```